# Excel IF - THEN with 2 actions

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that checks the value of a cell in column J. Based on the value I need to set the cells in column K and L for which I want to use the following code:

```
For Each Cell In TelRange
  With Cell
    If Left(.Value, 3) = 201 Then
      Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Mobile" And Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Left(Value, 5)
    End If
  End With
Next Cell
```

This however does not work.

Someone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: "Does not work" is not helpful. Does the code return an error? Does it do something you don't want it to do? Does it not do something you want it to do? Please provide details.

Comment: AND is a logical instruction to compare two values, not a way of making two things happen.

Answer (score 6):

From the question it sound like it works with 1 action but not with 2, right?
Try spliting it to two lines (AND is used for logical operations, like if A and B)

```
For Each Cell In TelRange
  With Cell
    If Left(Value, 3) = 201 Then
      Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Mobile"
      Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Left(Value, 5)
    End If
  End With
Next Cell
```

If it doesn't work, please say what's happening. error message? doesn't update?

Comment: Just want to point out that you are missing the `.` in `Left(Value, 3)` and `Left(Value, 5)`, plus if you are using `With Cell`, you can replace `Cell.Offset` with simply `.Offset`form inside the If. Not that the latter would cause any difference in the outcome, but would rather make the `With Cell` more meaningful